# Como selecionar Certificado Digital do usuário em aplicações Web?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nfe, certificado-digital

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto em ASP.NET MVC5 para fazer manifestação de notas fiscais eletrônicas.

Durante o processo de busca de notas, manifestação ou então download, faço acesso ao webservice da Receita Federal e preciso enviar o certificado digital referente ao CNPJ.

Tudo funciona certo enquanto eu estou desenvolvendo e testando as coisas localmente, mas quando a aplicação é publicada e vai para o servidor eu não consigo mais selecionar o certificado digital que quero utilizar.

Estou usando as classes **X509Certificate2**, **X509Store** e **X509Certificate2Collection**

Gostaria de fazer algo como neste link: https://cav.receita.fazenda.gov.br/eCAC/publico/login.aspx

Ao clicar na imagem do certificado digital, é aberto a Store contendo os certificados, porém só consigo fazer isso quando rodo a aplicação local, depois que vai para o servidor não consigo ter acesso a Store.

Alguém tem já trabalhou com isso ou saber como solucionar o problema?

Comment: Cara, tive muita dificuldade em usar certificado A3, pois o IIS não vai ter permissão de acesso aos certificados instalados no computador dos clientes, te sugiro usar um certificado A1.
Na época que havia começado a desenvolver o módulo de NF eu até cheguei a ler a respeito sobre uma API CAPICOM que ajudaria a usar A3, mas por simplicidade e praticidade eu optei por usar A1,

Comment: Entendo e sei que o A3 é muito problemático, mas eu não posso colocar essa limitação aos usuários. Eu tenho os 2 modelos para teste, e local tudo funciona certo, mas como é que os sites do governo conseguem utilizar da forma como usam no link que coloquei na pergunta? Deve existir algum modo da Certificate Store do Windows ser aberta por aplicações web e selecionar o certificado.

Comment: Sim, te entendo, mas acredito que tu terás que estudar a API CAPICOM pra abrir o repositório de certificados do windows, desconheço alguma maneira de fazer direto por C#.

Comment: @PabloVargas, mesmo que eu usar a CAPICOM e executar tudo no javascript, por exemplo...  Em certo momento eu vou precisar fazer o envio do certificado com os dados requeridos pelo webservice, dessa forma eu consigo fazer apenas pelo C#.  Existe alguma forma de fazer via javascript também?

Comment: Jefferson Pedro, você conseguiu encontrar a solução para seu problema? Como resolveu?

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde Jefferson, no site que você indicou somente é enviada para o servidor a chave pública do certificado, para assinar a NF-e é necessária a chave privada.

Quando implementei NF-e fiz um webservice e uma aplicação desktop local que baixava o XML, assinava, enviava para o servidor da receita e retransmitia o resultado para o webservice. Ainda acho a melhor estratégia.

Se vc precisa utilizar o site terá que usar o modelo A1 e referenciar diretamente o arquivo do certificado.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

Configure seu IIS para "Requerer Certificados Digitais", assim o servidor vai pedir o certificado dos clientes. Tanto faz se é certificado A3 ou A1.

Nessa pergunta o pessoal já explicou como fazer isso : [Como requisitar o certificado ssl do client IIS 7.5](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27899/como-requisitar-o-certificado-ssl-do-client-iis-7-5)

Answer (score 0):

fiz da seguinte maneira usando A1

```
private RecepcaoEvento.RecepcaoEventoSoapClient _nfeRecepcao;
    _nfeRecepcao.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, GetSerialCertificado());
     private string GetSerialCertificado()
            {
                X509Store store = new X509Store("My");
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
                foreach (var certificado in store.Certificates)
                {
                    if (certificado.SubjectName.Name.Contains(cnpj))
                    {
                        _serialCertificado = certificado.SerialNumber;
                    }
                }
                store.Close();
                return _serialCertificado;
            }
```

até momento esta funcionando em vários lugares dessa maneira.